# Dynamic creation of control

Tags: c#

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {

            Control control = new Control();

            control = new CheckBox();
            Size size = control.Size;
            Point point = new Point(20, 22);
            control.Location = point; 
            int width = size.Width + 5;
            i += width;
            list.Add(control);
        }

foreach(Control c in list)
{

}
```

how do I create a new instance of checkbox? Because this way I am getting just one checkbox each time. I want to get three checkbox in each row.

Comment: Could you include where you define "list". It's hard to understand your intentions without seeing what type "list" is.

Comment: List<Control> list = new List<Control>;

Answer (score 3):

Is this winforms? A first point: you don't need the `new Control()` each time (you simly discard it anyway when you `new CheckBox()`. How exactly do you want the layout to appear? Can you describe it a bit more please?

I imagine `TableLayoutPanel` might be a reasonable start...

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Form form = new Form();
    TableLayoutPanel layout = new TableLayoutPanel();
    layout.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    form.Controls.Add(layout);
    layout.AutoScroll = true;
    layout.ColumnCount = 3;
    // size the columns (choice just to show options, not to be pretty)
    layout.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 200));
    layout.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50));
    layout.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));    
    layout.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.Text = "item " + i;
        layout.Controls.Add(chk);
    }

    Application.Run(form);
}
```

Otherwise, you'll need to manually set the `Location` (or `Top` and `Left`) of each; not simple.

Comment: Actually I want to have a row of three checkboxes or a row of 3 labels depending upon the user dynamically in winform.

Comment: (oh, and set `layout.AutoScroll = true;`)

Comment: How do you set the column width?

Comment: because if you use label inplace of checkbox, columns look clustered

Answer (score 2):

Your code has problems.  Let's work from sample code rather than a lesson.  I'll create a Panel first, nice if you want to remove the checkboxes you created.  You'd probably be interested in the user clicking a checkbox so lets add an event for that.  Start a new WF project and drop a button on the form.  Double click it, then paste this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // Give the 3 checkboxes a decent spacing
  int height = this.Font.Height * 3 / 2;
  // Create the panel first, add it to the form
  Panel pnl = new Panel();
  pnl.Size = new Size(100, 3 * height);
  pnl.Location = new Point(10, 5);
  this.Controls.Add(pnl);
  // Make three checkboxes now
  for (int ix = 0; ix < 3; ++ix) {
    CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
    box.Size = new Size(100, height);
    // As pointed out, avoid overlapping them
    box.Location = new Point(0, ix * height);
    box.Text = "Option #" + (ix + 1).ToString();
    box.Tag = ix;
    // We want to know when the user checked it
    box.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(box_CheckedChanged);
    // The panel is the container
    pnl.Controls.Add(box);
  }
}

void box_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // "sender" tells you which checkbox was checked
  CheckBox box = sender as CheckBox;
  // I used the Tag property to store contextual info, just the index here
  int index = (int)box.Tag;
  // Do something more interesting here...
  if (box.Checked) {
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You checked option #{0}", index + 1));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you get your 200 instances, all placed at the same point.

Comment: It's actually not doing that. He alters 'i' in the loop. He adds the size of the control + 5 to it. I don't know how big a checkbox is, but he will probably add 10 every iteration, so something like 20 instances.

Comment: True. So it only remains to add i to one of the coordinates in the point.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate 3 new checkboxes inside your loop body, set their properties accordingly and add each of them to the list. After the code above is complete, you will have 600 checkboxes.

list.Add(Control1);

list.Add(Control2);

list.Add(Control3);

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you are trying to do, but I cleaned up your code a bit:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{

    Control control = new CheckBox();

    control.Location = new Point(20, 22); 
    i += control.Size.Width + 5;

    list.Add(control);
}
```

You should not add a new instance to the list if you want to add the control you just made.

Also:

```
Control control = new Control();
control = new CheckBox();
```

Is a bit redundant. Also to not get one control at the same spot multiple times you should alter the point. Hope this helps

Comment: and you'd have 200 controls all stacked on top of each other - adding i to control.Location each time would help :)

Comment: quote: "Also to not get one control at the same spot multiple times you should alter the point"

Comment: and the loop doesn't create 200 controls, look at my comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433833/dynamic-creation-of-control#433841