# Where to put WPF Dynamic Control Creation Code

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I am just in the process of teaching myself WPF. I have reached the point of adding controls dynamically and have hit a brick wall on something really simple. I code that should create a button (shown below):

```
Button button = new Button() { Height = 80, Width = 150, Content = "Test" };
parentControl.Add(button);
```

My question is what is `parentControl` actually called? I am using the standard Visual Studio 2012 WPF template and my main window is called `MainWindow`. I have no objects in the Window besides what comes in the template

So far I have looked at:

- [WPF runtime control creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491807/wpf-runtime-control-creation)
- [Dynamic control creation in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147829/dynamic-control-creation-in-wpf)
- [WPF MVVM Dynamic control creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156445/wpf-mvvm-dynamic-control-creation)
- [Dynamic creation of control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433833/dynamic-creation-of-control)
- [Where should I put WPF specific code when using MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654730/where-should-i-put-wpf-specific-code-when-using-mvvm)
- [Steps Of Control Creation Process WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859730/steps-of-control-creation-process-wpf)
- [Where to put code in (primarily) windowless WPF app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029131/where-to-put-code-in-primarily-windowless-wpf-app)

The closest I have found it: [WPF runtime control creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491807/wpf-runtime-control-creation).

All of these questions just assume you know such a basic thing but I don't. Please help.

Comment: I don't know in what context you're using your code in (a longer example could help), but if you need to know the type of `parentControl` you can just use `parentControl.GetType()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I understand your question. If your XAML code looks like:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
</Window>
```

Then your codebehind should be something like:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Button button = new Button() { Height = 80, Width = 150, Content = "Test" };
    //In case you want to add other controls;
    //You should still really use XAML for this.
    var grid = new Grid();
    grid.Children.Add(button);
    Content = grid;
}
```

However, I warmly suggest you to use XAML as much as you can. Furthermore, I wouldn't add controls from the constructor but I'd use the `Loaded` event of the window. You can add a handler to the event in codebehind from the constructor, or directly in XAML. If you wanted to have the same result as above in XAML, your code would be:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Height="80" Width="180" Content="Test"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Eve :-) Can you explain why you warmly suggest using XAML as much as I can? Thanks again.

Comment: @Brett Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421372/why-to-avoid-the-codebehind-in-wpf-mvvm-pattern

Comment: @Brett Use `DataTemplates` to generate controls on the fly.